# Combinations for the selection of 10 pens

Tags: probability, combinations

I have a problem I'm not so sure how to solve. Here's what it says:

A man needs to buy 10 pens at a store, there are 4 different brands W,X,Y and Z of blue pens, the pens that belong to each brand are identical, meaning that two pens from X are identical, two of Y are identical and so forth.

How many ways can the man buy 10 pens if the store only has 3 pens available of brand X?

I'm not sure what to do I've thought about it for a while and I was thinking about using the addition rule for the cases in which 1,2 and 3 pens of X were selected. However I'm not sure if I should use inclusion-exclusion, given that the events of choosing an pen of X are not disjoint.

Comment: Consider the cases where $\color{red}{\mathbf 0}, 1, 2,$ or $3$ pens of brand X are selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.

If pens are indicated by stars (*) and different types are separated by bars (|) then we have 
$$\underbrace{****}_W\big|\underbrace{***}_X\big|\underbrace{**}_Y\big|\underbrace{*}_Z$$
as a possible combination. Shifting the bars around gives different number of pens of brand $W, X, Y, Z$. Assuming it's possible to have none from a particular brand, it would be possible to have two or more bars next to each other.

Note that there are 10 stars representing the 10 pens, but only 3 bars (and not 4) to separate the 4 different brands. The total number of positions occupied by the stars and bars is $10+3=13$.

The total number of combinations is therefore the same as picking 3 positions out of 13 to place the bars, i.e.
$$\binom{10+3}3=\binom {13}3=286$$
This is if there are no restrictions on the number of any brand.

**Given that there is a limit on brand $X$,** we isolate that by choosing pens from brand $X$ first.

If we choose $r (0\le r\le 3)$ pens from brand $X$, that leaves $(10-r)$ pens to be chosen from $3$ other brands, i.e. only $2$ bars required. Therefore, the number of combinations is 
$$\sum_{r=0}^3\binom{10-r+2}2 =\binom {12}2+\binom {11}2+\binom{10}2+\binom 92=\color{red}{202}$$

Comment: Also a good way to go.  But watch out for the 3 pen limit on brand $X$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks for pointing that out. The above applies for the no-restriction case. Additional restrictions would have to be imposed to limit $X$ to 3.

Comment: Edited to take into account limit on brand $X$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help. I was stuck with this for a while.

Comment: You're most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the solution! It's quite an interesting question, esp with the cap (no pun intended!) on the pens, so I've posted an improvised version of the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409280/improvised-question-combination-of-selection-of-pens)

Answer (score 1):

The boy can go on saying $yes, yes, yes....$ until he gets the desired number of that type and then say $no$ and move on to the next type. For type Z he can just go on saying *yes* until 10 *yeses* reached, there is no need to say $no$.

The only question is how to arrange the 10 *yeses* and 3 *noes* which is ${13\choose 3}$

To exclude > 3 pens of type X, imagine 4 such have already been chosen and we need only 6 more, so following the same procedure, there will be ${9\choose 3}$ cases which we need to subtract.

$${13\choose 3} - {9\choose 3} = 202$$

Comment: very nice solution (+1). (btw its $X$ not $W$)